# Telerik RadComboBox: Everytime Check-All is selected I get the JavaScript error: A script on this page is causing your web browser to run slowly

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, telerik, telerik-combobox

I  have a RadComboBox that has around 400 items (from a DataBase) and I get the following JavaScript error as soon as I select "Check All":

> A script on this page is causing your web browser to run slowly. If it continues to run, your computer might become unresponsive.

To optimize the CombBox I have set LoadOnDemand to true & OnClientItemsRequesting="StopRequest", but this does not seem to help.

ComboBox Properties aspx code:

```
        <telerik:RadComboBox ID="CUD" 
            Width="260" 
            Height="150" 
            runat="server" 
            AutoPostBack="false" 
            CheckBoxes="true"
            EnableCheckAllItemsCheckBox="true">

            </telerik:RadComboBox>
```

Comment: Try using FireFox with FireBug to see whether it's the callback to the server taking too long, or if its related to a JavaScript file running.  I had that happen in 3 scenarios so far: 1) there was an infinite loop 2) the bandwidth of the client machine was very slow or 3) the page had to process a LOT of DOM elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the TelerikRadComboBox, I created a test project and tested with just the DropDown and 400 ListItems (and clicked CheckAll) and got the same error. There was no JavaScript executed that was personally written. An Admin responded saying thank you for reporting the error, your implementation is accurate I will forward the issue to the Development team for performance improvements... In general IE8 is slower than the others like some of you have mentioned which is why the error is caused solely on IE8.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention the browser in question, but I'm guessing it's IE8?

You're probably asking Javascript to do too much. You can't make this perform well across all common browsers as-is.

What possible use is a list of 1000 checkboxes to the user anyway? Why not think about this in a different way, allowing the user to filter the list to a more usable size.

Comment: O it is 400, I double checked. I'm sorry for confusion. IT is 400 and I want to be able to display 400 records corresponding to the list items and export them. & yes it is IE8, I don't understand why it would take so long to select 400 items... I can paste all of the other JavaScript code & CodeBehind if need be

Comment: @MyName I had that message pop up when selecting 631 items within a RadTreeView control, so it sounds very similar.

Comment: Alright, I'll double check the loops to see if they're efficient. There is no infinite loop for sure because the browser merely freezes for a couple of seconds then resumes with all 400 items selected.

Comment: It is not the JavaScript Im doubting a lot I want to just scrap the entire thing and redo it

Comment: I think this would make sense, try to find a better way to present this to the user.